# Include creator in tag_synonym

Tags: feature-request, api, tags, api-v2.1

When I looked at [recent tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) there is a Creator row, but I can't query this data with the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tag-synonyms#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

I'd like to see this data added, and a list of all approves would be nice too.